# How do I properly loop through a portion of code using methods in a class?

Tags: python

I am learning about classes in Python and tried to make a simple battle game. This code runs fine and as long as I print `devin.battle()` multiple times, but I want a while loop so that it will revert back to asking if the user would like to start a battle while also deducting the attack from the hit points.

```
start_battle = input("Would you like to start a battle? Y/N ===>  ")

class People:
        max_hit_points = 150
        current_hit_points = 150
        current_strength = 5
        defence = 0

        def __init__(self, name, current_hit_points):
            self.name = name
            self.current_hit_points
            self.damage = 50
            

        def battle(self):
            if start_battle == "Y":
                self.attacked()
            elif start_battle == "N":
                print("okay, nevermind then")
            
        def attacked(self):
            self.current_hit_points -= self.damage
            print("You have been attacked")
            if self.current_hit_points > 0:
                print("Try again newb!")
            else:
                print("Your HP has reached 0, you are dead")

        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self. name} has {self.current_hit_points}HP remaining"
        


devin = People("Devin", 150)
devin.battle()
print(devin)
```

However, when I add one to the whole thing Python freezes up.

```
start_battle = input("Would you like to start a battle? Y/N ===>  ")

class People:
        max_hit_points = 150
        current_hit_points = 150
        current_strength = 5
        defence = 0

        def __init__(self, name, current_hit_points):
            self.name = name
            self.current_hit_points
            self.damage = 50

        while current_hit_points > 0:
            def battle(self):
                if start_battle == "Y":
                    self.attacked()
                elif start_battle == "N":
                    print("okay, nevermind then")
                
            def attacked(self):
                self.current_hit_points -= self.damage
                print("You have been attacked")
                if self.current_hit_points > 0:
                    print("Try again newb!")
                else:
                    print("Your HP has reached 0, you are dead")

            def __str__(self):
                return f"{self. name} has {self.current_hit_points}HP remaining"
            continue
        
        else:
            print("You are dead") 

devin = People("Devin", 150)
devin.battle()
print(devin)
```

If anyone can explain to me why its freezing up and how I can properly loop a battle, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your loop doesnt have any stop condition. you define a bunch of functions and then do it again and again.... did you mean to put a `break` there instead of `continue`? what is the loop supposed to do? as it stands now it doesnt really do anything

Comment: @Nullman I'm trying to Loop it back asking if the user would like to battle until ```current_hit_points``` = 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues here and its not super clear what you are trying to do but here is some direction according to your comment, make sure ot read the `# code comments`

```
class People:
        max_hit_points = 150
        current_hit_points = 150
        current_strength = 5
        defence = 0

        def __init__(self, name, current_hit_points):
            self.name = name
            # you forgot to actually assign the hit points
            self.current_hit_points = current_hit_points
            self.damage = 50

        def battle(self):
            while self.current_hit_points > 0:
                # you want to ask the user every round?
                start_battle = input("Would you like to start a battle? Y/N ===>  ")
                if start_battle == "Y":
                    self.attacked()
                    # note that the user didnt get to attack back
                    # maybe print(self) here so the user can see his hp?
                elif start_battle == "N":
                    print("okay, nevermind then")
                    break
            else:
                print("You are dead") 
                
        def attacked(self):
            self.current_hit_points -= self.damage
            print("You have been attacked")
            if self.current_hit_points > 0:
                print("Try again newb!")
            else:
                print("Your HP has reached 0, you are dead")

        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self. name} has {self.current_hit_points}HP remaining"

devin = People("Devin", 150)
devin.battle()
print(devin)
```

Comment: Thank you! Where exactly was it freezing up? Was it where I had the loop to begin with? Instead of trying to loop the whole program, I should only loop the method that has the battle sequence?Sorry, while loops are becoming a hard concept for me when I'm trying to do actual things with them.

Comment: @DevinHight yes, the main issue was the location of the loop. the loop didnt run any code, it just redefined(not run, just define) the same functions over and over again, due to this the loop had no exit condition, no way to stop